# workbox.runtimeCaching.Handler in workbox 3?

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I have implemented this class in workbox 2, now I have upgraded to version 3 but workbox.runtimeCaching.Handler is deprecated.

Can someone help me on how to develop it in workbox 3?*

```
    importScripts('workbox-sw.prod.v2.1.2.js');
    importScripts('workbox-runtime-caching.prod.v2.0.3.js');
    importScripts('workbox-cache-expiration.prod.v2.0.3.js');

    const workboxSW = new self.WorkboxSW();

    class AlwaysNetworkWithCacheUpdateHandler extends workbox.runtimeCaching.Handler{

        setCacheOptions(cacheOptions){
            this.cacheOptions = cacheOptions;
        }

        handle({event}){
            let requestWrapper = new workbox.runtimeCaching.RequestWrapper({
                cacheName: this.cacheOptions.cacheName,
                plugins:[
                    new workbox.cacheExpiration.CacheExpirationPlugin(this.cacheOptions.expirationOptions)
                ]
            });
            return (
                requestWrapper
                    .fetchAndCache({
                        request: event.request,
                        waitOnCache: true
                    })
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are going to reach, however, I used runtimeCaching for third-party requests (CDN), so now it is handling by regular way:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/handle-third-party-requests

Answer (score 0):

Strategies now do the job of `RequestWrapper`, choose one and use like so:

```
const strategy = workbox.strategies.networkFirst({
  cacheName,
  plugins: [
    new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
      maxEntries: 100,
      maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 *7,
    })
  ],
});

const handler = async ({event}) => {
  const request = new Request(event.request, {
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'omit',
  });

  const cachedResponse = await caches.match(request, {
    cacheName,
  });

  return cachedResponse || strategy.makeRequest({
    event,
    request,
  });
}

router.registerRoute(
  ({ url }) => url.origin === 'http://example.com',
  handler,
)
```

Example comes directly from [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/938)